# How to implement multilevel expandable listView for following Layout, or any other way to achieve this?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview

[image]I am trying to implement a view which as follows :

**Group_1**
*subGroup_1*
->Network Call, populate data. (onClick event another list opens)(ListView)
->  Network call, populate data (ListView)
*subGroup_2*
->Network Call, populate data. (onClick event another list opens)
->  Network call, populate data

SubGroup_1 and SubGroup_2 are hardcoded. Onclick of SubGroup_1 a network call is made and a list is populated say List_dataset_1, then
again onClick event of List_dataset_1 another network call is made and another list view is populated.

I tried using expandable ListView with no success. Please suggest me a way to implement this type of view or can Expandable list view be used to achieve this result?

Comment: could you post diagram/figure/image, what view you likely to do implement?

Comment: @Sam I have added the picture

Answer (score 0):

I got your question. I am just giving you an idea about How can you implement above scenario. The following code is just demo. you have to implement your own. see following code :

This is GroupExpandableAdapter:

```
public class GroupExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<Group> mGroupList;
        private Context mContext;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private SubGroupExpandableAdapter mSubGroupExpandableAdapter;


        public GroupExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groupList) 
        {
            this.mGroupList = groupList;
            this.mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() 
        {
            return mGroupList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
        {
            return 1;           // for child expandable list view
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
        {

            return mGroupList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {

            // implement your groupView code that you want to show
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,  boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ChildHolder childHolder;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_sub_group_expandable_view, null);

                childHolder = new ChildHolder();
                childHolder.subGroupExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sub_group_expandable_view);

                convertView.setTag(childHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            initializeSubGroupAdapter(groupPosition);
            childHolder.subGroupExpandableListView.setAdapter(mSubGroupExpandableAdapter)
            return convertView;
        }


        private void initializeSubGroupAdapter(int groupPosition) 
        {
            mSubGroupExpandableAdapter = new SubGroupExpandableAdapter(mContext, mGroupList.get(groupPosition))
        }


        private static class ChildHolder
        {
            ExpandableListView subGroupExpandableListView;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

following code is for your subGroup:

```
 public class SubGroupExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<SubGroup> mSubGroupList;
        private Context mContext;
        private Group mGroup;

        public SubGroupExpandableAdapter(Context context, Group group) 
        {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.mGroup = group;
            this.mSubGroupList = group.getSubGroupList();
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() 
        {
            return mSubGroupList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
        {
            return mSubGroupList.get(groupPosition).getItemOfSubGroup().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
        {
            return mSubGroupList.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return mSubGroupList.get(groupPosition).getItemOfSubGroup().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() 
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // Implement your subGroup view here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,  boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // Implement itemOfSubGroup view here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This your MainActivity from here you have to pass model data:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private ExpandableListView mGroupExpandableListView;
    private GroupExpandableAdapter mGroupExpandableAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Group> mGroupList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();
    }


    private void initView() 
    {
        mGroupList = new ArrayList<Group>(); // fill your modeldata from server
        mGroupExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.groupExpandableListView);

        initializeAdapter();
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() 
    {
        mGroupExpandableAdapter = new GroupExpandableAdapter(MainActivity.this, groupList)
        mGroupExpandableListView.setAdapter(mGroupExpandableAdapter);
    }
}
```

hope it helps you.

Comment: I want to send data obtained from first API call to make second api call. I want to do this on click listener.

Comment: you can use `onGroupClickListener` for onClick of group of `ExpandableListView`.  go to through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) document, that might be helps you.